# Labeling information of another atribute

Tags: labeling

I have this attribute table:

[image]

I want to run a script for labelling:

```
label=''  
parametros=array("Alumínio","Antimônio")

for i in range(len(parametros)):
    label=prof[i]
    if ID_sprof[i]==ID_sprof[i-1]:
        label+=prof[i-1]
```

This is a try of labeling the Profs of the next attribute together with the previous one.
for example, considering that SO-31 has 3 Prof, I wanted one labelling like:

0,6 1,6 3,0

This is a resume of what I'm trying. I know this doesn't work in an expression. But this can be done by making some changes and defining a function in the expression editor.

This is just an example how I could access the information of another atribute to put in the other, but I know it doesn't work.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Answer (score 3):

For QGIS, use this expression:

```
array_to_string(array_agg(Prof, group_by:=ID_sprof))
```

You can add an optional argument between the second last and the last closing bracket `)` to define (a) delimiter character(s) like this: `delimiter:=' '` - what is inside the single quotes `'` (here: a space  `enter code here`) will be used as a delimiter. Use `\n` to insert a linebreak and get a separate row for each value.

Comment: Do you know where can i learn more about this?

Comment: I'm trying to use that inside a function, when i run the function it goes well.
But in the "expression" it acuses 'array_to_string' is not defined.
Is it a native expression in qgis?
When i just put the expression directly in the "expression" it works

Comment: Documentation for QGIS expressions: https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html `array_to_string()` should work in newer QGIS versions.

Comment: Please, could you see my other question?

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/460202/functions-in-the-expression-tab-used-in-function-editor?noredirect=1#comment751565_460202